# GET request gets triggered after DELETE

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a web app in django for the first time and one of the features is adding and editing vacancies. Some info is added using forms and POST method (title of the vacancy, description, etc.) And other fields are added and removed dynamically to the DOM and database with Fetch api (duties, offers, advantages).

When loading the edit vacancy view, the duties, offers and advantages, as well as the form data are pre loaded from the database.

The problem arises when trying to remove the pre-loaded duties, offers and advantages from the edit vacancy view. When i send a DELETE request, something is triggering a GET in the edit view, causing everything to reload. This is not ideal, since all previous user input is gone.

This only occurs with the edit view, the new vacancy view works as intended with both adding and removing the dynamic fields without page refreshing.

How can i prevent the DELETE request from the removeduty triggering the GET on edit ? And why could this be occuring ?

**Video demo:**

**intended behavior**: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlrOx2OyoAY) ( works when adding a new vacancy. Items are added and deleted without refresh. Log shows PUT and DELETE requests as expected.) :

**bug:** [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZpkt-FQnBU) (how the page currently behaves in edit view. Page refreshes after deleting the item. DELETE request is immediately followed by an unwanted GET request):

**edit views.py:**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def edit(request,id):
    if request.method =="POST":
        vacancy = Vacancy.objects.get(pk=id)

        newtitle = request.POST['title']
        newcity = request.POST['city']
        newcountry = request.POST['country']
        newimage = request.FILES.get('image')
        newdescription = request.POST['description']

        vacancy.title = newtitle
        vacancy.city = newcity
        vacancy.country = newcountry
        vacancy.description = newdescription

        if newimage:
            vacancy.image = newimage

        vacancy.save()

        if vacancy.image:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))
        else:
            return render(request,'app/cms-edit.html',{
                'vacancy': vacancy,
                'imagemessage': 'Please add an image'
            })
        
    if request.method=="GET":
        vacancy = Vacancy.objects.get(pk=id)
        title = vacancy.title
        city = vacancy.city
        country = vacancy.country
        description = vacancy.description
        image = vacancy.image
        
        duties = Duty.objects.filter(vacancy=vacancy)
        offers = Offer.objects.filter(vacancy=vacancy)
        advantages = Advantage.objects.filter(vacancy=vacancy)
        
        return render(request,'app/cms-edit.html',{
            'vacancy': vacancy,
            'duties':duties,
            'offers':offers,
            'advantages':advantages,
        })
```

**removeduty views.py:**

```
@csrf_exempt   
def removeduty(request,id):
    duty = Duty.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "DELETE":
        duty.delete()
        return JsonResponse({"message":"duty deleted"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"message":"duty not deleted"})
```

**removeduty javascript**

```
//remove duty
    function removeduty(dutyid) {
        let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        let parent = document.getElementById(`dutyitem-${dutyid}`);
        parent.remove()
    
        fetch(`removeduty/${dutyid}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result.message);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error deleting duty:', error);
        });
    }
```

**relevant part of edit vacancy html**

```
<div id="dutysection" class="dutyitems">
            {% if duties %}
            {% for duty in duties%}
              <div class="cms-added-item" id="dutyitem-{{duty.id}}">
                <p class="cms-added-list-item">{{duty.text}}</p>
                <div class="action-wrap-app">
                  <a href="" class="trash-icon w-inline-block" onclick ="removeduty({{duty.id}})">
                    <div class="delete w-embed"><svg width="auto" height="32" viewbox="0 0 36 39" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M12.0841 29.526L18.0363 23.4738L24.0504 29.526L26.8744 26.6641L20.9102 20.5999L26.8744 14.5358L24.0504 11.6619L18.0363 17.726L12.0841 11.6619L9.22219 14.5358L15.2124 20.5999L9.22219 26.6641L12.0841 29.526ZM6.87654 38.8597C5.85041 38.8597 4.94768 38.4732 4.16834 37.7002C3.38904 36.9272 2.99939 36.0253 2.99939 34.9945V6.51948H0.746094V2.65428H11.157V0.798828H24.8657V2.65428H35.2765V6.51948H33.0233V34.9945C33.0233 36.0253 32.6356 36.9272 31.8603 37.7002C31.085 38.4732 30.1802 38.8597 29.1461 38.8597H6.87654Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                      </svg></div>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            {% endfor%}
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
```

**related url patterns**

```
    path("edit/<int:id>",views.edit,name="edit"),
    path("edit/addduty/<int:id>",views.addduty,name="addduty"),
    path("edit/removeduty/<int:id>",views.removeduty,name="removeduty"),
    path("edit/addoffer/<int:id>",views.addoffer,name="addoffer"),
    path("edit/removeoffer/<int:id>",views.removeoffer,name="removeoffer"),
    path("edit/addadvantage/<int:id>",views.addadvantage,name="addadvantage"),
    path("edit/removeadvantage/<int:id>",views.removeadvantage,name="removeadvantage"),
```

Here is the log of what happens when the removeduty function runs. You can see that it triggers GET on the edit causing it to refresh. But why ?

[07/Aug/2023 09:03:47] "DELETE /edit/removeduty/202 HTTP/1.1" 200 27

[07/Aug/2023 09:03:47] "GET /edit/250 HTTP/1.1" 200 8895

**Edit:** I tried to add another if condition for the edit view, to return if the request.method == "DELETE", to see if that would prevent it from happening, but that did nothing.

I suspect this issue might have something to do with the way i have set up my url patterns. I created seperate patterns for the edit view, since the regular ones did not work.

here are the url patterns used to create the items from the add new vacancy view ( which works as intended )

```
path("addduty/<int:id>",views.addduty,name="addduty"),
path("removeduty/<int:id>",views.removeduty,name="removeduty"),
path("addoffer/<int:id>",views.addoffer,name="addoffer"),
path("removeoffer/<int:id>",views.removeoffer,name="removeoffer"),
path("addadvantage/<int:id>",views.addadvantage,name="addadvantage"),
path("removeadvantage/<int:id>",views.removeadvantage,name="removeadvantage"),
```

Could this be causing some sort of conflict that triggers the GET request and causes the refresh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding "javascript:void(0);" in the href tags of the remove buttons instead of "#" or leaving them empty.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="trash-icon w-inline-block" onclick ="removeduty({{duty.id}})">
```

Comment: An alternative approach is to use AJAX call to prevent reloading the page

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the `duty.id` being supplied as a parameter directly to an inline function it would be cleaner to use an externally registered event handler that inspects the (click) `event` to identify the element and from that deduce the `duty.id` assigned to either event.target or suitable parent.

The inline SVG images could be replaced with `use` elements if you were to store the all paths for all SVG images elsewhere (see below) - this would make the HTML smaller as the full path is only written once rather than perhaps dozens of times.

The event handler is listening for clicks on the SVG elements so the hyperlink effectively does nothing now except provide the `data-dutyid` value that is consumed within the event handler. In the snippet the `duty.id` values were replaced with hardcoded numeric values only as a "for-instance" - these would be `{{duty.id}}` in the real code.

```js
const getCookie=(name)=>`Some code to find a cookie named:"${name}"`;
const getresponse=(r)=>r.json();
const callback=(r)=>console.log(r.message);
const errorhandler=(e)=>console.warn('Error deleting duty: %o',e);


document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof SVGUseElement || e.target instanceof SVGSVGElement ){
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let dutyid=e.target.closest('a').dataset.dutyid;
    let config={ 
      method:'delete',
      headers:{ 'X-CSRFToken':getCookie('csrftoken') }
    };
    
    e.target.closest('div.cms-added-item').remove();
    
    fetch( `removeduty/${dutyid}`, config )
      .then( getresponse )
      .then( callback )
      .catch( errorhandler )
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="dutysection" class="dutyitems">
  <!-- example hardcoded items - loop removed -->
  <div class="cms-added-item">
    <p class=" cms-added-list-item">BANANA</p>
    <div class="action-wrap-app">
      <a href="#" class="trash-icon w-inline-block" data-dutyid="303">
        <div class="delete w-embed">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 36 39"  height="32" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
            <use href="#trashcan" />            
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cms-added-item">
    <p class=" cms-added-list-item">WOMBLE</p>
    <div class="action-wrap-app">
      <a href="#" class="trash-icon w-inline-block" data-dutyid="304">
        <div class="delete w-embed">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 36 39"  height="32" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
            <use href="#trashcan" />            
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cms-added-item">
    <p class=" cms-added-list-item">{{duty.text}}</p>
    <div class="action-wrap-app">
      <a href="#" class="trash-icon w-inline-block" data-dutyid="{{duty.id}}">
        <div class="delete w-embed">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 36 39"  height="32" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
            <use href="#trashcan" />            
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>














<!--
  If you use lots of SVG images on the page, rather than add the full path inline with the HTML 
  every time you add the image it would be better to maintain the `path` elements within a `defs`
  element as below and call it using `use`
-->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" aria-hidden="true" style="position:absolute; width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; display:none">
    <defs>
        <symbol id="trashcan">
            <path d="M12.0841 29.526L18.0363 23.4738L24.0504 29.526L26.8744 26.6641L20.9102 20.5999L26.8744 14.5358L24.0504 11.6619L18.0363 17.726L12.0841 11.6619L9.22219 14.5358L15.2124 20.5999L9.22219 26.6641L12.0841 29.526ZM6.87654 38.8597C5.85041 38.8597 4.94768 38.4732 4.16834 37.7002C3.38904 36.9272 2.99939 36.0253 2.99939 34.9945V6.51948H0.746094V2.65428H11.157V0.798828H24.8657V2.65428H35.2765V6.51948H33.0233V34.9945C33.0233 36.0253 32.6356 36.9272 31.8603 37.7002C31.085 38.4732 30.1802 38.8597 29.1461 38.8597H6.87654Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
        </symbol>
    </defs>
</svg>
```